# Refiners for multi-valued managed properties in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, search, refinement-panel, refiner

Refiners for multi-valued managed properties do not behave like they do for Site Columns when they are created. Values are being refined to "Value one;Value two;Value three" instead of:

- Value one - (3)
- Vaue two - (4)
- Value three - (5)

I've seen SharePoint 2010 posts that answer the question but not 2013. Any help would be a appreciated!

Comment: I would love to know where those posts are for 2010 as I know nothing about this

Answer (score 1):

Actually separators are not used any longer in SharePoint 2013. The multivalue field needs to be populated using a `List` of items, e.g. `List<string>`.

I'm using Content Enrichtment to populate my field using `Property<List<string>>` ; a good example from Microsoft:

[How to: Use the Content Enrichment web service callout for SharePoint Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163982%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

I found another interesting sample in the Microsoft forums:

[Index a multiple value column in BCS external content type "SharePoint 2013"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/7fa6fe7b-8ea5-42eb-b9d6-fa396da3eff9/index-a-multiple-value-column-in-bcs-external-content-type-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Not true, List<> is not an acceptable value for a property. Only string, int and DateTime are

Comment: List<string> is accepted. You just need to make the Managed Property accept multiple values. Please make this a marked answer! Also here a Link with a good sample: http://www.blendmaster.net/blog/2012/09/using-content-enrichment-web-service-callout-in-sharepoint-2013-preview/

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Filter based on the OOB MultiField one. Split the filters into new filters, instead of hex use the actual plain text value.

I have described everything here:
https://hyankov.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/sharepoint-2013-refiner-multi-value-contains-instead-of-an-equals/

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this question in SharePoint 2013 is to make the Managed Property 'Allow multiple values'.  This is done through Search Schema in the settings list.

This allows a single option to match, even when multi-choices are selected.